# Error while running a slurm job through crontab which uses Intel MPI

Tags: mpi, slurm, intel-mpi

I am trying to run WRF (real.exe, wrf.exe) through the crontab using compute nodes but compute nodes are not able to run slurm job. I think there is some issue with the MPI library when it's running through the cron environment.

Tried to replicate the terminal path variables while running the crontab job.
The log file generated while running job on terminal and crontab is attached as with_terminal and with_crontab respectively in the link.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YE9OchSB8alpZSdRl-8uIbBPm6lI-0DQ

Error while running the job from crontab is as follows

```
#################################
compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
#################################
Processes 4
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] check_exit_codes (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/demux/hydra_demux_poll.c:117): unable to run bstrap_proxy on compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1 (pid 23070, exit code 65280)
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] poll_for_event (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/demux/hydra_demux_poll.c:159): check exit codes error
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] HYD_dmx_poll_wait_for_proxy_event (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/demux/hydra_demux_poll.c:212): poll for event error
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] HYD_bstrap_setup (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/bstrap/src/intel/i_hydra_bstrap.c:772): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] main (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/mpiexec.c:1938): error setting up the boostrap proxies
```

Thanks for looking in the issue.

Comment: questions should be self-contained. for security reasons, many SO users (including myself) will not click any link to 3rd party websites (such as google drive)

Comment: Will you please guide me about how can I attach the log files to this question

Comment: simply edit your question and copy/paste the logs in a code block.

Comment: Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790257/error-while-running-a-slurm-job-through-crontab-which-uses-intel-mpi-for-paralli