# Error while running a slurm job through crontab which uses Intel MPI for parallization

Tags: mpi, slurm, intel-mpi

I am trying to run WRF (real.exe, wrf.exe) through the crontab using compute nodes but compute nodes are not able to run slurm job. I think there is some issue with the MPI library when it's running through the cron environment.

Tried to replicate the terminal path variables while running the crontab job. The log file generated while running job on terminal and crontab is attached below.

Slurm log while running from terminal is as follows

```
SLURM_NODELIST=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
LDFLAGS=-L/shared/gccWRF/grib2/lib
SLURM_JOB_NAME=real_slurm_run_wrf.sh
MANPATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/man:/opt/slurm/share/man
XDG_SESSION_ID=2226
WRF_DIR=/shared/gccWRF/WRF
SLURMD_NODENAME=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
SLURM_TOPOLOGY_ADDR=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
HOSTNAME=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
SLURM_PRIO_PROCESS=0
SLURM_NODE_ALIASES=(null)
SHELL=/bin/bash             ---------------------------
TERM=xterm          -----------------------------------
HISTSIZE=1000              ------------------------
CPPFLAGS=-I/shared/gccWRF/grib2/include
TMPDIR=/tmp             
SLURM_TOPOLOGY_ADDR_PATTERN=node
SSH_CLIENT=157.33.216.217 58485 22                -----------------------------
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib
JASPERINC=/shared/gccWRF/grib2/include
QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3      ----------------------------------------
DIR=/shared/gccWRF
QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include                      ----------------------------
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2        ------------------------
SHARED_DIR=/shared
SLURM_NNODES=1
USER=ec2-user
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/release:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/lib
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:           ------------------------------------------
TARGET_DIR=/shared/FORECAST/domains/test/     ------------------------
FI_PROVIDER_PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib/prov           
SLURM_JOBID=72
SLURM_NTASKS=8
SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE=8
PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/bin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin:/shared/gccWRF/netcdf/bin:/shared/gccWRF/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/opt/amazon/openmpi/bin/:/opt/amazon/efa/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/slurm/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/ec2-user           ----------------------------------------
FCFLAGS=-m64
SLURM_WORKING_CLUSTER=parallelcluster:172.31.32.246:6820:9216:109
SLURM_CONF=/opt/slurm/etc/slurm.conf
SLURM_JOB_ID=72
JASPERLIB=/shared/gccWRF/grib2/lib
SLURM_JOB_USER=ec2-user
PWD=/shared/foreasting/wrf          -----------------------
_LMFILES_=/opt/intel/impi/2019.8.254/intel64/modulefiles//intelmpi
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
MODULEPATH=/opt/intel/impi/2019.8.254/intel64/modulefiles/
SLURM_JOB_UID=1000
LOADEDMODULES=intelmpi
SLURM_NODEID=0
F77=gfortran
SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR=/shared/foreasting/wrf
SLURM_TASK_PID=8972
SLURM_NPROCS=8
SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE=8
CXX=g++
SLURM_PROCID=0
ENVIRONMENT=BATCH
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups   ------------------------------
SLURM_JOB_NODELIST=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
BUILDDIR=/shared/build/gccWRF
HOME=/home/ec2-user
SHLVL=2 --------------------
SLURM_LOCALID=0
KMP_AFFINITY=granularity=fine,compact,1,0
SETUP_DIR=/shared/hpc-workshop-wrf
WPS_DIR=/shared/gccWRF/WPS
SLURM_JOB_GID=1000                    
SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE=8
SLURM_CLUSTER_NAME=parallelcluster
FC=gfortran
SLURM_GTIDS=0
SLURM_SUBMIT_HOST=ip-172-31-32-246
NETCDF=/shared/gccWRF/netcdf
SLURM_JOB_PARTITION=compute
LOGNAME=ec2-user
QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib           ---------------------------
CLASSPATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/mpi.jar      
SSH_CONNECTION=157.33.216.217 58485 172.31.32.246 22   ------------------
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/ec2-user/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share               ----------------------------
KMP_STACKSIZE=128M
GEOG_BASE_DIR=/shared/FORECAST/domains/
SCRIPTDIR=/shared/gccWRF/bin
SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES=1
MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules        --------------------------------
OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s      -------------------------------------
CC=gcc
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
I_MPI_ROOT=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi
FFLAGS=-m64
BASH_FUNC_module()=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`   ----------------
}              -------------------------
_=/usr/bin/env
#################################
compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
#################################
Processes 4
 starting wrf task            0  of            4
 starting wrf task            1  of            4
 starting wrf task            2  of            4
 starting wrf task            3  of            4
```

slurm log while running from crontab is as follows

```
SLURM_NODELIST=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
SLURM_JOB_NAME=real_slurm_run_wrf.sh
LDFLAGS=-L/shared/gccWRF/grib2/lib
MANPATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man -------------------------------------
XDG_SESSION_ID=2233
SLURMD_NODENAME=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
SLURM_TOPOLOGY_ADDR=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
HOSTNAME=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
WRF_DIR=/shared/gccWRF/WRF
SLURM_PRIO_PROCESS=0
SLURM_NODE_ALIASES=(null)
SHELL=/bin/sh
TMPDIR=/tmp
SLURM_TOPOLOGY_ADDR_PATTERN=node
CPPFLAGS=-I/shared/gccWRF/grib2/include
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib
JASPERINC=/shared/gccWRF/grib2/include
DIR=/shared/gccWRF
SHARED_DIR=/shared
SLURM_NNODES=1
USER=ec2-user
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/release:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/lib
TARGET_DIR=/shared/FORECAST/domains/test/
FI_PROVIDER_PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib/prov
SLURM_JOBID=70
SLURM_NTASKS=8
SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE=8
PATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/bin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin:/shared/gccWRF/netcdf/bin:/shared/gccWRF/bin:/shared/gccWRF/netcdf/bin:/shared/gccWRF/bin:/opt/intel/impi/2019.8.254/intel64/modulefiles/:/usr/bin:/bin --------------------------------
SLURM_WORKING_CLUSTER=parallelcluster:172.31.32.246:6820:9216:109
SLURM_CONF=/opt/slurm/etc/slurm.conf
FCFLAGS=-m64
SLURM_JOB_ID=70
JASPERLIB=/shared/gccWRF/grib2/lib
SLURM_JOB_USER=ec2-user
PWD=/shared/foreasting/wrf
_LMFILES_=/opt/intel/impi/2019.8.254/intel64/modulefiles//intelmpi
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
MODULEPATH=/opt/intel/impi/2019.8.254/intel64/modulefiles/
LOADEDMODULES=intelmpi
SLURM_JOB_UID=1000         
SLURM_NODEID=0
SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR=/shared/foreasting/wrf
F77=gfortran
SLURM_TASK_PID=8643
SLURM_NPROCS=8
SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE=8
SLURM_PROCID=0
ENVIRONMENT=BATCH
CXX=g++
SLURM_JOB_NODELIST=compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
SHLVL=3
HOME=/home/ec2-user
BUILDDIR=/shared/build/gccWRF
SLURM_LOCALID=0
SETUP_DIR=/shared/hpc-workshop-wrf
KMP_AFFINITY=granularity=fine,compact,1,0
SLURM_JOB_GID=1000
SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE=8
SLURM_CLUSTER_NAME=parallelcluster
WPS_DIR=/shared/gccWRF/WPS
SLURM_GTIDS=0
SLURM_SUBMIT_HOST=ip-172-31-32-246
FC=gfortran
SLURM_JOB_PARTITION=compute
NETCDF=/shared/gccWRF/netcdf
LOGNAME=ec2-user
CLASSPATH=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/mpi.jar
SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES=1
SCRIPTDIR=/shared/gccWRF/bin
GEOG_BASE_DIR=/shared/FORECAST/domains/
KMP_STACKSIZE=128M
OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
CC=gcc
I_MPI_ROOT=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi
FFLAGS=-m64
_=/usr/bin/env
#################################
compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1
#################################
Processes 4
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] check_exit_codes (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/demux/hydra_demux_poll.c:117): unable to run bstrap_proxy on compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1 (pid 8652, exit code 65280)
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] poll_for_event (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/demux/hydra_demux_poll.c:159): check exit codes error
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] HYD_dmx_poll_wait_for_proxy_event (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/demux/hydra_demux_poll.c:212): poll for event error
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] HYD_bstrap_setup (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/bstrap/src/intel/i_hydra_bstrap.c:772): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@compute-dy-c5n18xlarge-1] main (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/mpiexec.c:1938): error setting up the boostrap proxies
```

Thanks for looking into the issue.

Comment: Can you precise the command line you're using in each case ?

Comment: The actual command is "mpiexec.hydra -bootstrap slurm -np $PROCESS -ppn 18 ./wrf.exe". This command is present in the bash file which is I am running using the command of "sbatch --ntasks 144 slurm_run_wrf.sh"

Comment: with cron, there are references to intel mpi 2019 that are not present otherwise and this is odd. try resetting your module (e.g. `. /etc/profiles.d/modules.sh; module purge; module load intelmpi` in your script)

Comment: already using (module unload intelmpi; module load intelmpi) in the bash script.

Comment: Tried resetting module by module purge but faced the same error.

Comment: We can see that you are able to run WRF using MPI in Slurm. There may be an integration issue with Crontab.